# Manage Client Socket Pool

Tags: java, sockets, pool, socketchannel

I need to manage long running TCP socket connections to an external server from my Java application. I'm looking for a good socket pool so I will be able to re-use the sockets.

There is another solution than `org.apache.commons.pool2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some object pool implementations you may try:

- [Vibur Object Pool](http://www.vibur.org/vibur-object-pool/)
- [fast-object-pool](http://danielw.cn/fast-object-pool/) 
  [image: Fast Object Pool vs Commons Pool v1.x]

I suggest you to benchmark the object pool implementations in order to find the most appropriate one for your project.